# error finding/accessing a data file in python

Tags: python, file, directory, path, errno

I receive this error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SomaStuhl/SomaFinal.csv'

I've read thru several stackoverflow answers for this problem

1. the file is in the same directory as the Python code accessing the file
2. No matter whether I use the relative or absolute path, I get this error
3. I tried:
   import sys
   sys.path.append(r'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SomaStuhl')
   but still got Errno 2

New Python user

Comment: Did you try copy and pasting the link in windows file explorer to see if it opens correctly?

Comment: Add code snippet

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure that what you are trying to access exists, do the following:

```
import csv

from pathlib import Path

# Navigate from the file explorer, copy the path and assign it as a path to a variable.
# We are using Path object because it automatically recognizes windows paths
my_path = Path("C:/Users/username/Documentd/Research/SomaStuhl")

# Then check if it exists
my_path.exists()
# if the output is True it means it found the path
# then try to list the items of that directory to make sure it is there
list(my_path.iterdir())

# if it is there read it like that just to be sure it works with the built-ins

# we will use joinpath to make sure we correctly extend from the existing path and enumerate to emulate the bash command 
# head SomaFinal.csv -n5


# the with statement means it will close the file when it finishes reading the file
with my_path.joinpath('SomaFinal.csv').open() as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # idx comes from enumerate and row from reader, 1 means start counting from 1
    for idx, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        print(row)
        if idx == 5:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you.  Very detailed.  I will work on this tomorrow

Comment: Thank you, everyone one for these answers.

Comment: Thank you, everyone for these answers.  I went for simplest first, looking for the file. Although it was in my Windows 10 Explorer directory, when I used cd, change directory, I got message "Name is nonexistent or
not a folder".  I changed the name of the folder from SomaStuhl to SOMA. When I opened the file in Matlab or Python with the path: C:\Users\Owner\Research\SOMA\SomaFinal.csv, I was able to access the file. I have no idea why the folder name SomaStuhl didn't exist but the folder SOMA does.  Thanks again.  I